# Where is the documentation for MSAjax and WebFormsJS in .NET 4.5?

Tags: jquery, .net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I have been Googling this for a bit now and I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I created a new web application in VS2012 using .NET 4.5. It created a ton of files. Most I understand and have seen before except the Scripts->WebForms contents. I know what the Ajax Control Toolkit is however I have never seen anything like what I see here with javascript.

My question is, where can I find documentation on things like SmartNav.js or TreeView.js? I do not know what these do or how to implement the functions inside the files. I gather that these relate somehow to the Ajax Control Toolkit as there is a folder with them called MSAjax (another folder with .js files I do now know what to do with).

[image: File_Structure]

I feel like I am missing out on some great tools here. I normally use jQueryUI but I have always used Visual Studio 2010 or older for my .NET web development and it never came with files like these pre populated.

If this question is already answered somewhere, I will gladly close it but I could not find anything myself. Maybe I am just bad with Google.

I found an inordinate amount of links leading me here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874(v=vs.100).aspx

and here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420390.aspx

but they do not answer my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing in the Scripts-WebForms directory is the ASP.NET 4.5 ScriptManager Improvements in WebForms, specifically the decoupling of Ajax script files and WebForms script files.  Previously, these scripts all lived inside the assembly System.Web.dll and therefore the scripts did not need to be deployed separately.  Unfortunately that approach lacked control of the individual scripts.  Now these scripts are served from your application Scripts folder which makes them easily redistributable and updateable.

Regarding documentation on things like TreeView.js (as well as the rest of the script files), there is a reason your searches haven't found anything.  These script files are specifically for supporting ASP.NET WebForms controls and Microsoft Ajax.  They are the "internal" javascript that enable WebForm controls like asp:TreeView to work the way they do.

You aren't missing out on any great tools.  Just use WebForm controls like asp:TreeView and you'll be using TreeView.js!

Answer (score 0):

If you open the `system.web` dll in ILSpy under resources you would find the scripts referenced in the `site.master` page for example

```
asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js"
```

The file `TreeView.js` is found in the `system.web` resources folder.